Upload Google Sheet with App Script to FTP Server
I have a Google Sheet in my Google Drive, and I would like to know if there is a way to automatically upload this sheet to an FTP server (created with FileZilla) using a trigger.

Related Google Drive as FTP Server

As stated by TheMaster, (S)FTP is not supported. Best alternative within Google's ecosystem is to use its FaaS(Function as a Service) solution - Google Cloud Run Functions -instead. Cloud Run Functions are an enterprise-grade solution but its comes with a free tier - so as long and you don't need to process crazy workloads you should be good.

Apps script doesn't support (S)FTP - (Secure)File Transfer Protocol. A feature request was made in the issuetracker.  You can add a +1(top right) to the tracker to show your interest as well as explain how it will profit your business in the comments. See:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36757386
